# Undefined control sequence, when using font in tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, nodes

I get the following error when using `font` keyword in TikZ node

```
Undefined control sequence ...t=\small,black,rotate=90] at (-1/4,22/4) {
```

where the code is,

```
\node[font=\small,black,rotate=90] at (-1/4,22/4) {$W_1$};
```

If I remove `font=\small`, there is no error. What is the problem and how I should avoid it?

Edit1: Minimum Working Example,

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw[fill=brown,opacity=.8,very thin,line join=round]
         (0,0) -- (-0.5,0) -- (-0.5,11) -- (0,11) -- cycle;
    \node[font=\small,black,rotate=90] at (-1/4,22/4) {$W_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I use `texlive 2012` in Ubuntu 11.10, if it makes any difference.

Comment: I don't have any problems with your code. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Remove the `class=minimal` option from your `documentclass` options. `minimal` doesn't provide any font sizes, which is why `font=\small` causes an error.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks a lot! It solved the problem :)

Comment: Related: [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-not-use-the-minimal-class)